# Encode Wave file to G.722 using Naudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, rtp

I have C# RTP application where i can send G.711 encoded audio without any problem.
Now i'm trying to add G.722 Support as well using Naudio.

This method is working but with too much noise

```
public byte[] Encode(byte[] data, int offset, int length)
    {
        G722Codec codec = new G722Codec();
        int bitrate = 64000; //Bits per sample = 8
        G722CodecState encoderState = new G722CodecState(bitrate, G722Flags.SampleRate8000);

        if (offset != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("G722 does not yet support non-zero offsets");
        }

        var wb = new WaveBuffer(data);
        int encodedLength = length/2;
        var outputBuffer = new byte[encodedLength];
        int encoded = codec.Encode(encoderState, outputBuffer, wb.ShortBuffer, length/2);
        return outputBuffer;
    }
```

And if i change the stream sampling rate to 16k or 22k it is not working at all.

Any ideas ?

Comment: what doesn't work at 16kHz?

Comment: Sorry Mark I have changed the G722Flags to none and it's working with (16k) wave file but the sound contains too much noise and I don't know why

Comment: Hello @MarkHeath can you please help me with that ?